# Ruby-LDAP and Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby, macos, ldap, osx-snow-leopard

When I install Ruby-LDAP on my Snow Leopard box, all appears to go well:

```
$ sudo gem install ruby-ldap
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ruby-ldap-0.9.9
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for ruby-ldap-0.9.9...
Installing RDoc documentation for ruby-ldap-0.9.9...
```

But when I run the Ruby script that relies on it, I get this error:

```
in 'require': no such file to load -- ldap (LoadError)
```

I also tried setting ARCHFLAGS, since doing so appears to be required for the MySQL gem to function correctly in Snow Leopard:

```
$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install ruby-ldap
```

Unfortunately, this produces exactly the same results (or lack thereof).

How do I get Ruby to work with the LDAP libraries correctly here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you

```
require 'rubygems'
```

first.

Comment: Haha! Well, aren't I an idiot? That's what I get for trusting inherited code.

That did the trick. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

gem install ruby-ldap